# CoReleaseMarshalData usage

Tags: com, marshalling

I have a thread A (the main STA thread) that creates a COM object and want to pass it to another thread so I use `CoMarshalInterface` API.

Thread B (MTA/STA no matters) processes many types of events where one of them is to receive the stream and call `CoUnmarshalInterface` to get the proxy object.

Because the call to `CoUnmarshalInterface` may fail (for any reason), if it occurs, I must call `CoReleaseMarshalData` to free the stream data but, MSDN documentation says:

> Important: You must call the `CoReleaseMarshalData` function in the same
>   apartment that called `CoMarshalInterface` to marshal the object into
>   the stream. Failure to do this may cause the object reference held by
>   the marshaled packet in the stream to be leaked.

So, in thread A, I implemented a wait after the `CoMarshalInterface` call and check if `CoUnmarshalInterface` succeeded or not but the problem is that while I wait, if thread B or another one makes a remote-com operation, because thread A is blocked waiting for the result, I get a deadlock.

I also tried using `CoWaitForMultipleHandles` with no luck.

Is really needed to call `CoReleaseMarshalData` in the same apartment? Do you know another approach to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have does not seem to be related to marshaling itself. Yes you do `CoUnmarshalInterface` to release marshaling stream from the apartment where you created it, but the problem appears to be the interthread synchronization, not the marshaling itself:

> So, in thread A, I implemented a wait after the CoMarshalInterface call and check if CoUnmarshalInterface succeeded or not but the problem is that while I wait, if thread B or another one makes a remote-com operation, because thread A is blocked waiting for the result, I get a deadlock.

When you have the stream on hands and you send the call to another apartment, important is how exactly you are waiting. Since you are in STA, you should still dispatch window messages on the thread while waiting (e.g. using `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx`). You, instead, are assuming the block will be short term ans messages can wait for a while. Then if you have a backward call relying on message dispatch on thread A - this is where deadlock comes in.

So the problem in first place is blocking STA thread, including blocking message dispatch. Wait while dispatching messages, or put the stream into a safe place for later release, you don't need to hurry with `CoUnmarshalInterface` that much, and you can release the resources later at your first convenience.

Comment: Hi @Roman, I do the wait using `CoWaitForMultipleHandles` but result is the same. I can remove the wait, let the program continue its execution. Thread B will take the stream and call `CoUnmarshalInterface` but, if unmarshalling fails, can I safety call `CoReleaseMarshalData` in thread B or should I, for e.g., use QueueUserAPC targetting thread A to release the marshal data? Basically the problem I have is with releasing the data, not with unmarshalling it.

Comment: Sure thing, you can have a flag (or the stream presence itself is such an indicator) that once `CoUnmarshalInterface` succeeded, you no longer need to call `CoReleaseMarshalData` on thread A.

Comment: Yes but my problem is where to call `CoReleaseMarshalData` if unmarshal fails. Queuing an user apc in thread A or I just can call it in thread B.